# How to search grid by textbox ID?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am Using jqgrid in mvc 4. I want to show grid data only those data which match with OrderNo. Grid is showing but data is not showing. Here is Controller where i am writing my sql search method for filtering data. please suggest me the better way to search data in grid view?

```
public ActionResult getItemsByOrder(string OrdNo)
{
    try
    {
        List<OrderDtl> itm = db.Fetch<OrderDtl>("select * from OrderDtls where OrderNo=" + OrdNo).ToList();
        return Json(itm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch
    {
        return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Here is my script. I think my problem is in url: line or in controller. Please Help me to solve my solution.

```
</script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/scripts/css/ui.jqgrid.css" title="coffee" media="screen" />
            <script src="~/Scripts/jqgrid/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/jqgrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/js/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/js/jqDnR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var ord = $('#OrderNo').val();
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/NewOrder/getItemsByOrder/' + ord,
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',

            colNames: ['ItemId', 'ItemName', 'Quantity', 'Rate', 'Amount', 'Action'],
            colModel: [
                          { name: 'ItemId', index: 'Id', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                          { name: 'ItemName', index: 'ItemName', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                          { name: 'Quantity', index: 'Quantity', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                          { name: 'Rate', index: 'Rate', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                          { name: 'Amount', index: 'Amount', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                          { name: 'Action', index: 'Action', width: 100, align: 'left' }
                      ],
            cellEdit: true,
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'ItemId',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            width: 950,
            imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
            caption: 'Order Details Grid'
        });

    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried looking for errors in the firebug or firefox dom inspector or chrome's DOM inspector?

Comment: @Johnx yah i have tried in firebug in firefox it is showing no url found

Comment: well that says it all try specifying the url with the helper method `Url.Action` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx